# Matlab: Overwrite "nameless" add-key-value-pair method

Tags: matlab, containers

I would like to inherit from superclass **containers.Map** and change the behaviour of the add-new-key-value-pair method. 
Syntax for adding a new key value pair to a **containers.Map** is

```
myMap = containers.Map();
myMap('myKey') = myValue;
```

**I don't know which method to overwrite**, as no explicit methodname is used like shown above.

thanks in advance,

mmm

**Update:**
My latest approach is

```
classdef CarMap < containers.Map

methods
    function A = subsasgn(A, S, B)            
        disp('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');            
        A = subsasgn@containers.Map(A, S, B);
    end
end
```

But `subsasgn` is not called when I do `myObj('someKey') = someValue;`

Any advice?

Comment: I think you want to override either `subsref` or `subasgn`...

Comment: I've never tried it but this might be helpful http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br09nsm

Comment: Thank you for your help,... yes that is exactly what I was looking for: subsasgn(a,s,b)
Here is a link which refers to overloading operators in matlab:
http://www.mathworks.de/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html

Comment: Maybe you should add an answer with worked code?

Comment: I am still playing around with Matlab. Now I know what to search for, but I still don#t have it running. As soon as I have a working example I will post it.
In between feel free to post further suggestions :)